# Retrieving form field and display value in fancybox

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, iframe, fancybox

I am trying to create a basic form with one text field.  When a user inputs a code into the text field.  Then when they click submit I will have an iframe pop up with the url + their text field value.

Everything looks to me like it is setup correctly but the fancybox loading screen never goes away and iframe never shows.

This is my sample of what is not currently working:

```
<form id="Form" onsubmit="fancybox.iframe('http://www.regonline.com/eventinfo.asp?eventid=' + document.Form.Event.value);return false;" autocomplete="off" style="height: 100%;" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Contact/tabid/59/Default.aspx" method="post" name="Form">
    <input type="text" name="Event">
</form>

<?PHP
    $eventid = $_POST['Event'];
    echo '<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.regonline.com/eventinfo.asp?eventid='. $eventid .'">Submit</a>';
?>
```

This does work but it opens another window and I cannot get it working with fancybox iframe:

```
<form id="Form" onsubmit="window.open('http://www.regonline.com/eventinfo.asp?eventid=' + document.Form.Event.value);return false;" autocomplete="off" style="height: 100%;" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Contact/tabid/59/Default.aspx" method="post" name="Form">
    <input type="text" name="Event">
    <br>
    <a class="event" onclick="window.open('http://www.regonline.com/eventinfo.asp?eventid=' + document.Form.Event.value);" href="#">Submit</a>
</form>
```

I'm sure this is super simple for the right set of eyes, be gentle ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing some code or you didn't paste it all.

Where is the form submission handled? I see you have a link and the href is what you want for the iframe value, but I'm not understanding the connection between it all.

If on clicking the link it populates the input field called Event, then you're actually populating it with the whole url. If you're then using that field to populate the iframe in your onsubmit line, then you're actually appending the whole url to the url again, creating a url like this in the end: http://www.regonline.com/eventinfo.asp?eventid=http://www.regonline.com/eventinfo.asp?eventid=SOME_ID_NUMBER

Without seeing all the code, I'm speculating that you really want the href in the submit link to only include the $eventid value and not the whole URL.

So your code might need to be:

```
 echo '<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="'. $eventid .'">Submit</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks @SaidK, I actually want the link to populate like this: http://www.regonline.com/eventinfo.asp?eventid=WHAT_USER_SUBMITS_IN_TEXTFIELD_EVENT.  So in otherwords I have a textbox where the user will enter a number, When they click my link "submit" then it will open the above url in the fancybox iframe with their value taking place of WHAT_USER_SUBMITS_IN_TEXTFIELD_EVENT.  So in otherwords if I enter 12345 in the textfield and click submit then my fancybox iframe will load the url http://www.regonline.com/eventinfo.asp?eventid=12345.  Hope that makes sense.  thx

Comment: You could do this, (unless you want to process the user's input by sending it to your script and then afterward open the iframe once the page reloads):

<form id="Form" onsubmit="fancybox.iframe('http://www.regonline.com/eventinfo.asp?eventid=' + document.Form.Event.value);return false;" autocomplete="off" style="height: 100%;" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Contact/tabid/59/Default.aspx" method="post" name="Form">
    <input type="text" name="Event">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: For the above, all I did was add <input type="submit" value="Submit"> within the form. This will trigger your form's onsubmit. @Derek

Comment: thanks, that actually just takes me to mydomain.com/Contact/tabid/59/Default.aspx in a new window instead of the regonline url + eventid in a fancy box.  Any other thoughts?  I guess what I should ask is because that second snippet I use in my question works, how to I effectively replace window.open with something to call the fancybox iframe.  I tried fancybox.iframe but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, this is actually what I was looking for and somehow I ended up getting it right.  Thanks again for the help

```
<form id="Form" autocomplete="off" style="height: 100%;" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" name="Form">
                            <input type="text" name="Event">
                            <br>
                            <a id="event-link" class="event" href="#">Submit</a>
                        </form>
                        <script>
                        $('#event-link').click(function () {
                            $.fancybox({
                                type: 'iframe',
                                href: 'http://www.regonline.com/eventinfo.asp?eventid=' + document.Form.Event.value
                            });
                        });
                        </script>
```